# Microsoft Graph subscriptions return no notifications

Tags: notifications, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I am trying to subscribe to the Microsoft Graph resource for notifications.
I send a subscription request:

```
{
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": "<!-- WEBHOOK URL --!>",
"resource": "/communications/presences/<!-- user id --!>/",
"expirationDateTime": "2022-04-25T13:30:00.0000000+00:00",
"clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

I receive confirmation:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity",
"id": "9596a9f7-5e67-47bf-9368-33c447183725",
"resource": "/communications/presences/<!-- user id --!>/",
"applicationId": "de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064",
"changeType": "updated",
"clientState": "SecretClientState",
"notificationUrl": "<!-- WEBHOOK URL --!>",
"notificationQueryOptions": null,
"lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
"expirationDateTime": "2022-04-25T13:30:00Z",
"creatorId": "55ee4d42-dbe2-49fb-8fff-63fcdfec136f",
"includeResourceData": null,
"latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
"encryptionCertificate": null,
"encryptionCertificateId": null,
"notificationUrlAppId": null
}
```

Afterwards the webhook forwards me a mail with the validation token message from Graph (for debugging): "'Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 9596a9f7-5e67-47bf-9368-33c447183725'"

In the Graph explorer it confirms that a subscription has been created when i list subscriptions.

But when i change presence it does nothing. I receive no hit on the webhook.
I even confirmed via the Graph explorer that my presence has changed in the Graph system.

I have also tested with postman with the "official Microsoft Graph" collection where there is a "Subscription validation" feature. It passes all three tests.

I also tried to subscribe for a mail created event. No notification here either.

This has been going on for days so i am fairly sure it is not because the API is temporarily down.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

As i checked above response code everything looks good, but make sure you have correct webhooks URL (must be https:), could you please try by extending "expirationDateTime", hope this docs will help you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http .

Subscriptions have a limited lifetime. Apps need to renew their subscriptions before the expiration time. Otherwise, they need to create a new subscription, For a list of maximum expiration times, - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-1.0#maximum-length-of-subscription-per-resource-type

[image]

reference docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation

Comment: As you told , when you change presence it does nothing , is it worked before ?

Comment: No, i have never made it work.

Comment: I have tried to set the maximum allowed expiration of 60 minutes for presence. The link is https. I am sure of it. I have tested within the expiration time. I can try to renew subscription and see if that helps for unknown reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the update , let us know if it works.

Comment: Is there any update on this?I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions on presence require resource data to be encrypted.

From [Create Subscription Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#presence):

> ### presence
>
> Subscriptions on presence require any resource data included in a change
> notification to be encrypted. Always specify the encryptionCertificate
> parameter when creating a subscription to avoid failure. See more
> information about setting up change notifications to include resource data.

Information on setting up subscriptions with encryption can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-with-resource-data?tabs=csharp)